# Is there a way to associate annotations/comments to a layer in PDF in Acrobat Reader

Tags: pdf, annotations, layer, acrobat

I have a layered PDF. I want to put comments or annotate only one layer in the pdf, but I wonder if it's possible in acrobat or any other application. Basically, I want to associate comments to layers. With Acrobat X, I could not find a way to insert comments only to one particular layer.

I think this is more of an application specific question, because PDF1.5 standard says, OCG can include annotation objects as well. May be there is no way to do so from the application, or I don't know how to achieve that. Any pointers, suggestions, advice to achieve this would be great.

Comment: A remark on the side: If you want to use references to the standard, you nowadays had better refer to the current ISO standard published [here by Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) or at least (if you prefer Adobe lingo to ISO standards) the PDF reference 1.7. That been said, also according to the standard any annotation can belong to an optional content group by means of an **OC** entry in the annotation dictionary, cf. section 12.5.2 in ISO 32000-1.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Exactly, annotation can be part of OC entry. But, looks like Acrobat or any known viewer does not have a way to put annotations specific to a layer. I am not sure, how will it behave if I create one such file manually and open in Acrobat.

Comment: *I am not sure, how will it behave if I create one such file manually and open in Acrobat.* - It's worth a try. Even if they do not allow to *create* everything possible according to the spec, they are pretty advanced in *showing* it properly.

Comment: Annotations, assigned to `OCG`s (which I did for a project about a year ago), *do* respect `on/off` state of `OCG`s, set in viewer's UI (Acrobat, Foxit and NitroPDF if I remember it right).

Comment: Thanks @VadimR. My concern is more about the entry point. Is there a way to assign the annotation to a layer in a Viewer. I can see that Acrobat Preflight has a way to achieve it. But as a end-user is there a way I can comment on a particular layer ONLY.

Comment: I am not sure if we can do that using an Application. But, we can do it through APIs or at least the PDF1.5 standards say that OCG can include annotation objects as well. Not sure if an application provides those flexibilities.